# Unable to add sails-mysql as non-default datastore

Tags: mysql, sails.js

I got stuck for days now, trying to add mysql to my sails project as a non default datastore. If anybody knows a solution. Please

It seems like the additional datastore inside config/datastores.js is not being registered, or the error that is showing is not correct.

"sails": "^1.4.0",
"sails-mysql": "^1.0.1"

I keep getting this error:

> error: A hook (`orm`) failed to load! error: Could not tear down the
> ORM hook.  Error details: Error: Invalid data store identity. No data
> store exist with that identity.

config/datastores.js

```
module.exports.datastores = {
default: {
    adapter: 'sails-disk',
},

mysqlDB: {
    adapter: 'sails-mysql',
    url: `mysql://${process.env.TC_DB_USERNAME}:${process.env.TC_DB_PASSWORD}@${process.env.TC_DB_HOST}:3306/Auth`,
},
};
```

api/models/Account.js

```
module.exports = {
 datastore: 'mysqlDB',
 schema: false,
};
```

As a workaround, I am using standard 'mysql' package to connect inside a helper. This works perfectly fine, but is resource heavy and I would love to get standard sails methods (Account.sendNativeQuery()) for the model to work.
If I can't get that to work, maybe someone can tell me how to make this connection global, so I only have to connect once and not on every helper call?

helpers/new-account.js

```
    var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: process.env.TC_DB_HOST,
    user: process.env.TC_DB_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.TC_DB_PASSWORD,
    database: 'Auth',
});

connection.connect();

module.exports = {
    friendlyName: 'Creates new account',

    description: 'returns the id of the new usr or throws error',

    inputs: {
        username: {
            description: 'The new account name.',
            type: 'string',
            required: true,
            minLength: 4,
            maxLength: 64,
        },
        salt: {
            required: true,
            type: 'ref',
            description: 'generated salt.',
        },
        verifier: {
            required: true,
            type: 'ref',
            description: 'generated verifier.',
        },
        email: {
            required: true,
            type: 'string',
            isEmail: true,
            description: 'Email linked to account.',
        },
    },

    exits: {
        success: {
            description: 'All done.',
        },
    },

    fn: async function ({ username, salt, verifier, email }, exits) {

        connection.query(
            'INSERT INTO account SET ?',
            { username, salt, verifier, email },
            function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    throw new Error(`MYSQL ERROR: ${err}`);
                } else {
                    console.log(`new user with id ${result.insertId} created.`);
                    exits.success(result.insertId);
                }
            }
        );

        connection.end();
    },
    };
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try requiring the `sails-mysql` package rather than just including the stringified name, for example:

```
module.exports.datastores = {
    default: {
        adapter: 'sails-disk',
    },
    mysqlDB: {
        adapter: require('sails-mysql'),
        url: `mysql://${process.env.TC_DB_USERNAME}:${process.env.TC_DB_PASSWORD}@${process.env.TC_DB_HOST}:3306/Auth`,
    },
};
```